# Stub yaml file in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to stub this method by loading mockup yaml file located in different directory.

Original configuration to stub:

```
  def load_environment_config(gateway, trx_type)
    @config = YAML.load_file("config/#{env}.yml")["#{env.upcase}"]
    raise "\n\nMissing gateway configuration for #{gateway} in file config/#{env}.yml!\n" unless @config[gateway]
    @terminal = terminal_for(@config, gateway, trx_type)
    @url = URI.parse("#{@config['processing_url']}#{@terminal['token']}")
  end
```

I tried this:

```
let(:yaml_file)           { YAML::load(File.read(File.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'yaml', 'test_env.yml'))) }
let(:config)              { yaml_file['TEST_ENV'] }

allow(request_builder).to receive(:config).with(config)
```

Error:

```
 Errno::ENOENT:
       No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - config/test_env.yml
     # ./models/request_builder.rb:50:in `load_environment_config'
```

What is the proper way to stub the file?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to explicitly load the file in the very first line of your method. You might put your `test_env.yaml` there in `config` directory in the first place.

You might also stub `YAML#load_file`:

```
let(:yaml) { YAML.load(File.read(....) }

allow(YAML).to \
  receive(load_file).
  with("config/#{env}.yml")).
  and_return(yaml)
```